# Issue with display div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing an issue for displaying a div on hover.

When I hover on the `div` element `A`, the `div` element `B` is displayed as per my expectation. But when mouse pointer leaves the `div` element `A`, the `div` element `B` does not disappear.

```js
 $('.display_cal').hover(function () {
          $('.calender_category_div').css("display" , "block");
      });
```

```css
  .datespan{
          display: block;
      }

      .calender_category_div{

          position: absolute;
          top: 40%;
          left: 50%;
          z-index: 1050;
          background: #FFFFFF;
          padding: 10px 20px;
          display: none;
      }

      .calender_category_div ul{
          padding: 0;
      }

      .calender_category_div ul a {
          color: #428bca;
          text-decoration: none;

      }

      .calender_category_div ul a:hover {
          color: #428bca;
      }

      .calender_category_div ul {
          color: #428bca;
          list-style-type: none;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<p style="float: right;color: #17469e;" class="display_cal">12 october 2016</p>

<div class="calender_category_div" >
                <ul>
                    <a id="fl_ical" href="http://addtocalendar.com/atc/ical?f=m&e[0][date_start]=2016-12-02%2009%3A00%3A00&e[0][date_end]=2016-12-02%2018%3A30%3A00&e[0][timezone]=Pacific%2FPitcairn&e[0][title]=StartupBridgeIndia&e[0][description]=StartupBridge%20India%20conference%20aims%20to%20foster%20cross-border%20partnerships%20%26%20collaboration%2C%20and%20open%20up%20investment%2Facquisition%20opportunities%20for%20US%20Tech%20companies%20in%20India.%20The%20event%20is%20organized%20by%20TiE%20Silicon%20Valley%2C%20iSPIRT%2C%20and%20Stanford%20Center%20for%20International%20Development%20(SCID)%20and%20will%20be%20held%20on%20December%202nd%202016%20at%20Stanford%20University.&e[0][location]=SIEPR%2C%20Stanford%2C%20CA&e[0][organizer]=iSPIRT%2C%20TIE%20%26%20SIEPR&e[0][organizer_email]=rajan%40ispirt.in&e[0][privacy]=public" target="_blank"><li>iCalendar</li></a>
                    <a id="fl_google" href="http://addtocalendar.com/atc/google?f=m&e[0][date_start]=2016-12-02%2009%3A00%3A00&e[0][date_end]=2016-12-02%2018%3A30%3A00&e[0][timezone]=Pacific%2FPitcairn&e[0][title]=StartupBridgeIndia&e[0][description]=StartupBridge%20India%20conference%20aims%20to%20foster%20cross-border%20partnerships%20%26%20collaboration%2C%20and%20open%20up%20investment%2Facquisition%20opportunities%20for%20US%20Tech%20companies%20in%20India.%20The%20event%20is%20organized%20by%20TiE%20Silicon%20Valley%2C%20iSPIRT%2C%20and%20Stanford%20Center%20for%20International%20Development%20(SCID)%20and%20will%20be%20held%20on%20December%202nd%202016%20at%20Stanford%20University.&e[0][location]=SIEPR%2C%20Stanford%2C%20CA&e[0][organizer]=iSPIRT%2C%20TIE%20%26%20SIEPR&e[0][organizer_email]=rajan%40ispirt.in&e[0][privacy]=public" target="_blank"><li>Google Calendar</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

What am I lacking?

Comment: could it be that you should have the div as "hidden" by default? so it would display on hover and go back to hidden if the mouse isnt over the div?

Comment: Why don't use only css for that ?

Comment: Another `div` means which div?

Comment: @Byakko_Haku.. yes..

Comment: You need to add the `calender_category_div` inside `p`. Replace `p` with`div tag`.  then in css it will work. no need of writing jquery

Comment: @Rishi answered with updated html. Please find below answer

Comment: @Samir... calender_category_div

Comment: You are displaying the same div only correct? which needs to be display ie. `.calender_category_div`.

Comment: Actually you have given position absolute to the `.calender_category_div`. May be because of this, the div is displaying somewhere else, not in the relevant position. Keep in mind, if you are using `position: absolute` then the parent of the same div should be in `position: relative`.

Comment: when i hover on date , then **calender_div** should display along with its contents , then when i hover on the contents of **calender_div** will remained same (should display). when i hover on else where , then only it **calender_div** should disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Two solution is there via ***jquery or css***

**update**:change `p` tag into `div`

css for the hover effect :

```
.display_cal:hover  >.calender_category_div{
  display:block;
  }
```

Its will give the `toggle` effect for you.

***or using jquery***

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('.display_cal').mouseover(function(){
    $('.calender_category_div').show();
    })
  $('.display_cal').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.calender_category_div').hide();
    })

  })
```

***updated example:***

```css
.datespan{
          display: block;
      }

      .calender_category_div{
         position: absolute;
          top:5px;
          right:-10;
        
          z-index: 1050;
          background: transparent;
          padding: 10px 20px;
          display: none;
      }
.display_cal:hover  >.calender_category_div{
  display:block;
  }

      .calender_category_div ul{
          padding: 0;
      }

      .calender_category_div ul a {
          color: #428bca;
          text-decoration: none;

      }

      .calender_category_div ul a:hover {
          color: #428bca;
      }

      .calender_category_div ul {
          color: #428bca;
          list-style-type: none;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div style="float: right;color: #17469e;" class="display_cal">12 october 2016

<div class="calender_category_div" >
                <ul>
                    <a id="fl_ical" href="http://addtocalendar.com/atc/ical?f=m&e[0][date_start]=2016-12-02%2009%3A00%3A00&e[0][date_end]=2016-12-02%2018%3A30%3A00&e[0][timezone]=Pacific%2FPitcairn&e[0][title]=StartupBridgeIndia&e[0][description]=StartupBridge%20India%20conference%20aims%20to%20foster%20cross-border%20partnerships%20%26%20collaboration%2C%20and%20open%20up%20investment%2Facquisition%20opportunities%20for%20US%20Tech%20companies%20in%20India.%20The%20event%20is%20organized%20by%20TiE%20Silicon%20Valley%2C%20iSPIRT%2C%20and%20Stanford%20Center%20for%20International%20Development%20(SCID)%20and%20will%20be%20held%20on%20December%202nd%202016%20at%20Stanford%20University.&e[0][location]=SIEPR%2C%20Stanford%2C%20CA&e[0][organizer]=iSPIRT%2C%20TIE%20%26%20SIEPR&e[0][organizer_email]=rajan%40ispirt.in&e[0][privacy]=public" target="_blank"><li>iCalendar</li></a>
                    <a id="fl_google" href="http://addtocalendar.com/atc/google?f=m&e[0][date_start]=2016-12-02%2009%3A00%3A00&e[0][date_end]=2016-12-02%2018%3A30%3A00&e[0][timezone]=Pacific%2FPitcairn&e[0][title]=StartupBridgeIndia&e[0][description]=StartupBridge%20India%20conference%20aims%20to%20foster%20cross-border%20partnerships%20%26%20collaboration%2C%20and%20open%20up%20investment%2Facquisition%20opportunities%20for%20US%20Tech%20companies%20in%20India.%20The%20event%20is%20organized%20by%20TiE%20Silicon%20Valley%2C%20iSPIRT%2C%20and%20Stanford%20Center%20for%20International%20Development%20(SCID)%20and%20will%20be%20held%20on%20December%202nd%202016%20at%20Stanford%20University.&e[0][location]=SIEPR%2C%20Stanford%2C%20CA&e[0][organizer]=iSPIRT%2C%20TIE%20%26%20SIEPR&e[0][organizer_email]=rajan%40ispirt.in&e[0][privacy]=public" target="_blank"><li>Google Calendar</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when i hover on the displayed div , it gets disappear

Comment: Then when the content will disappear?. clarify the when the content will disapper

Comment: when i hover on date , then **calender_div** should display along with its contents , then when i hover on the contents of **calender_div** will remained same (should display). when i hover on else where , then only it **calender_div** should disappear

Comment: Welcome..! happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `calender_category_div` inside `p`. Replace `p` with `div` tag. then in with help of `css` it will work. no need of writing `jquery`

```css
.datespan{
  display: block;
}

.calender_category_div{
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: none;
}

.calender_category_div ul{
  padding: 0;
}

.calender_category_div ul a {
  color: #428bca;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.calender_category_div ul a:hover {
  color: #428bca;
}

.calender_category_div ul {
  color: #428bca;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.display_cal:hover .calender_category_div{display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div style="float: right;color: #17469e;" class="display_cal">12 october 2016
<div class="calender_category_div" >
                <ul>
                    <a id="fl_ical" href="http://addtocalendar.com/atc/ical?f=m&e[0][date_start]=2016-12-02%2009%3A00%3A00&e[0][date_end]=2016-12-02%2018%3A30%3A00&e[0][timezone]=Pacific%2FPitcairn&e[0][title]=StartupBridgeIndia&e[0][description]=StartupBridge%20India%20conference%20aims%20to%20foster%20cross-border%20partnerships%20%26%20collaboration%2C%20and%20open%20up%20investment%2Facquisition%20opportunities%20for%20US%20Tech%20companies%20in%20India.%20The%20event%20is%20organized%20by%20TiE%20Silicon%20Valley%2C%20iSPIRT%2C%20and%20Stanford%20Center%20for%20International%20Development%20(SCID)%20and%20will%20be%20held%20on%20December%202nd%202016%20at%20Stanford%20University.&e[0][location]=SIEPR%2C%20Stanford%2C%20CA&e[0][organizer]=iSPIRT%2C%20TIE%20%26%20SIEPR&e[0][organizer_email]=rajan%40ispirt.in&e[0][privacy]=public" target="_blank"><li>iCalendar</li></a>
                    <a id="fl_google" href="http://addtocalendar.com/atc/google?f=m&e[0][date_start]=2016-12-02%2009%3A00%3A00&e[0][date_end]=2016-12-02%2018%3A30%3A00&e[0][timezone]=Pacific%2FPitcairn&e[0][title]=StartupBridgeIndia&e[0][description]=StartupBridge%20India%20conference%20aims%20to%20foster%20cross-border%20partnerships%20%26%20collaboration%2C%20and%20open%20up%20investment%2Facquisition%20opportunities%20for%20US%20Tech%20companies%20in%20India.%20The%20event%20is%20organized%20by%20TiE%20Silicon%20Valley%2C%20iSPIRT%2C%20and%20Stanford%20Center%20for%20International%20Development%20(SCID)%20and%20will%20be%20held%20on%20December%202nd%202016%20at%20Stanford%20University.&e[0][location]=SIEPR%2C%20Stanford%2C%20CA&e[0][organizer]=iSPIRT%2C%20TIE%20%26%20SIEPR&e[0][organizer_email]=rajan%40ispirt.in&e[0][privacy]=public" target="_blank"><li>Google Calendar</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add minor css on hover for the jerking date

Comment: i can't modify. i have to use `p` tag

Comment: form the w3 site:

The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
$(".calender_category_div").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".calender_category_div").css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: when i hover on the displayed div , it gets disappear

Comment: I thought you wanted it to disappear when your mouse was removed from .display_cal? What is your desired effect for the div that appears on hover?

Comment: when i hover on date , then calender_div should display along with its contents , then when i hover on the contents of calender_div will remained same (should display). when i hover on else where , then only it calender_div should disappear

Comment: Is this the effect your after?